# Flowplayer is reloaded and nothing happens afterwards

Tags: flash, mp4, flowplayer

I'm trying to use flowplayer, but got some problems with it.
Since it has some methods, I need to implement some logics with external control elements, for example `play()`.

But calling these methods causes video element to reload and nothing happens after. What may cause this problem?

```
<a href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv" style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px" id="player">
</a>

<script>
  vplayer = flowplayer("player", "../flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
    clip: {
      autoPlay: false,
      autoBuffering: true
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, the problem was in a local file. If you share your page throygh the web server everything works fine.